# Ordering between formal theories by provability of consistency

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness, meta-math

I am studying proof theory with Girard's monograph from '87 ('proof theory and logical complexity').

1.5.6. is an exercise called 'ordering between theories'.

It reads as follows:

" (i) Let $\textbf{G}$ be the set of all primitive recursive extensions of $\textbf{EA}$ containing $\textbf{PRA}$; define the following relation of $\textbf{G}$:

$$ \textbf{T} < \textbf{U}  $$
if and only if  $$
\textbf{U} \vdash (Con(\textbf{T})) $$

and show that < is irreflexive and transitive: < is a strict order.

(ii) Is it possible to have $\textbf{T}, \textbf{U} \in \textbf{G},\textbf{T} \vdash (Con(\textbf{U})) ,\textbf{U} \vdash (Con(\textbf{T})) $?

(iii) If $ \textbf{T} < \textbf{U}  $ and $\textbf{T} \vdash A$, with $A$ a closed $\Pi^0_1$ -formula, show that $\textbf{U} \vdash A$."

I think (ii) is quite obviously impossible, since then by transitivity we would have a theory proving its own consistency, which is impossible by the second incompleteness theorem.

But I don't know how to deal with the transitivity from (i) or how to deal with (iii).

Thanks,
Ettore

Comment: Here is a hint that may help with transitivity ($W < T$ and $T < U$ implies $W < U$). We are assuming that these theories include PRA. So, for example, if $\lnot \text{Con}(W)$ then every one of these theories proves $\lnot \text{Con}(W)$. Remember $\text{Con}(W)$ is $\lnot \ulcorner W \vdash 0 = 1\urcorner$. Moreover, if $W \vdash 0 = 1$ then $U \vdash \ulcorner T \vdash \ulcorner W \vdash 0 = 1\urcorner  \urcorner $. This is because there is a primitive recursive function that takes a $W$ derivation of $0 = 1$ to a $T$ derivation of $\ulcorner W \vdash 0 = 1\urcorner$.

Comment: I should have written $T < W$ and $U < T$ implies $U <W$ to match the rest of my comment.

Comment: @Carl: Hey Carl thanks! I think the first half of your comment led me to an idea, but I think it's too easy to be right: For transitivity, assume $W \nvdash Con(U)$. Hence $PRA \nvdash Con(U)$, since W contains PRA. But then also $T \nvdash Con(U)$, since a provable $\Sigma^0_1$ - statement would already be provable in PRA, and Con(U) is a $\Sigma^0_1$ - statement. Contradiction. But I guess it must be wrong because I didn't use the other premise and also the rest of your comment.

Comment: Besides...a question: When in line 2 you write $\neg Con(W)$ you simply mean that W is not consistent, right? Or did you mean this to be provable in one of the theories? (I wondered because you wrote it so formally, that it could be meant as a formal statement, in a deduction.)

Comment: Con(W) is a $\Pi^0_1$ statement, but you are circling around the right idea. If $\lnot \text{Con}(U)$ then $T$ would prove $\lnot \text{Con}(U)$. What we want is the formalization of that: $W \vdash \lnot \text{Con}(U) \to \ulcorner T \vdash \lnot \text{Con}(U)\urcorner$.

Comment: Mmhhh...maybe things get (I admit: slowly) clearer. It seems that as $T \vdash \neg Thm_U(0=1)$, also $W \vdash Thm_T (\neg Thm_U (0=1))$, and so, since W proves T's consistency, $W \vdash \neg Thm_T ( Thm_U (0=1))$, and so, by your last derivation, we'd have transitivity. But still I am not sure about the details, have to think it over again. Awesome to have your support.. :)

Comment: I was imagining a proof by contradiction in $W$ - show that, within $W$, $\lnot \text{Con}(U)$ leads to a contradiction, because $W  \vdash \lnot \text{Con}(U) \to \ulcorner T \vdash \lnot \text{Con}(U)\urcorner$, and also $T > U$ leads to $W \vdash \ulcorner T \vdash \text{Con}(U)\urcorner$ , and from $\ulcorner T \vdash \text{Con}(U)\urcorner$ and $\ulcorner T \vdash \lnot \text{Con}(U)$, $W$ can prove $\lnot \text{Con}(T)$.

Comment: Dear Carl, thanks so much, I think I understand. Your argument seems simpler and straighter to me than mine, but do you think mine is also possible? A pitty I couldn't get it by myself. Does (iii) then easily follow? Please whenever you happen to have the time and like to visit my other questions don't hesitate to leave something, also short comments, they may help! :) Kind regards...

Comment: I think it will be a similar argument - $\lnot A$ is $\Sigma^0_1$, so $U \vdash \lnot A \to \ulcorner T \vdash \lnot A\urcorner$.  If you like, you would be welcome to write an answer in the answer box below (rather in the question box) to record it for others.

Comment: As for the reason that $W \vdash \text{Thm}_U(0=1) \to \text{Thm}_T\text{Thm}_U(0=1)$,  this is a special instance of the scheme $W \vdash \phi \to \text{Thm}_T(\phi)$ where $\phi$ is $\Sigma^0_1$. This scheme is the formalization into $W$ of the theorem (1.3.4) that EA proves every true $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence.  Girard claims this as theorem 1.4.7, so at least you have something to appeal to when solving his exercise.

Comment: Yeah I thought about writing it as an answer, but then it was rather yours than mine, it was only partially, SE sort of tells me to edit  my question rather then to answer it myself, and then also maybe it seemed a bit strange to me answering my own questions, well I also never answered any questions yet. I guess people can see it like this right? But you will have some experience with this site, if you suggest I will be happy to post it as a reply...still have to think about the mathematics in your last comments tomorrow, cheers!

Comment: I think I can see now, Carl. Still 1.4.7 'looks' slightly different to my eyes, a bit more complicated, as it speaks about substitutions of free variables for instance. But 1.3.4 (iii) is about every $\Sigma$ -sentence, right, not $\Sigma^0_1 $? Apparently $\phi$ is $\Sigma^0_1 $, no matter what theory U is, as  long as it is prim.rec., and T can be replaced by any theory extending EA, which is then I guess provable within any theory W that extends PRA.

Comment: @Carl: I added a proof for (iii), hope my view in my last comment is also correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{(Sketch of a) proof of transitivity (i):}$

We may suppose that $W$ is consistent, for if it is inconsistent it proves anything.

Assume $W \vdash Thm_U(0=1)$ - we're after a contradiction $in$ $W$.

We have $W \vdash Thm_U(0=1) \rightarrow Thm_T(Thm_U(0=1))$.
This is an instance of theorem 1.4.7., that is the formalization of 1.3.4. (iii).

Hence $W \vdash Thm_T(Thm_U(0=1))$.

Since $T \vdash \neg Thm_U(0=1)$, also $W \vdash \neg Thm_U(0=1)$.
It think this is because if the statement is provable in some theory extending EA, it is provalbe in $any$ theory extending EA, but I am not sure.

So: $W \vdash Thm_T(\neg Thm_U(0=1))$.
It think that should be possible for any theory T, as long as T is prim.rec.

Now, I guess it is not difficult to see that, although not sure about the precise way how to do it, from $W \vdash Thm_T(\neg Thm_U(0=1))$ and $W \vdash Thm_T(Thm_U(0=1))$, it follows that $W \vdash Thm_T (0=1)$.

But we already know from the beginning that $W \vdash \neg Thm_T (0=1)$.

So we get a contradiction in $W$ by assumption of $W \vdash Thm_U(0=1)$, thus we get $W \vdash \neg Thm_U(0=1)$.

It seems to me that a lack of my understanding comes from not really knowing what the provability predicate is able to do. It seems to me that my textbook didn't clarify these things very explicitly, or at least I didn't notice. Specifically the predicate was never used for different theories at the same time (in this intricated way).

$\textbf{Now an offer for a proof of (iii):}$

We head for a contradiction within $U$.
Suppose $U \vdash \neg A$.

$\neg A$ is a $\Sigma^0_1$ -sentence, since $A$ is a $\Pi^0_1$ -sentence.
Hence by theorem 1.4.7. (1.3.4. (iii) within PRA) $U \vdash \neg A \rightarrow Thm_T(\neg A)$, as $U$ contains PRA and $T$ extends EA, and thus $U \vdash Thm_T(\neg A)$.

But since $T \vdash A$, also $U \vdash Thm_T(A)$ by theorem 1.3.4., as long as $T$ is any prim. rec. theory and $U$ extends EA, since $Thm_T(A)$ is a true $\Sigma$ -sentence.

So by $U \vdash Thm_T(\neg A)$ and $U \vdash Thm_T(A)$ also $U \vdash Thm_T(\neg A \land A)$, that is $U \vdash Thm_T(0=1)$.

But we have as a premise that $U \vdash  \neg Thm_T(0=1)$.

So we derived a contradiction in U from $U \vdash \neg A$.
So $U \vdash A$.

Comment: For $W \vdash \text{Thm}_T(\lnot \text{Thm}_U(0=1))$, we have assumed $U <T$ so $T \vdash \lnot \text{Thm}_U(0=1)$ and we have $T \vdash \lnot \text{Thm}_U(0=1)$ implies $\text{EA} \vdash \text{Thm}_T(\lnot \text{Thm}_U(0=1))$.  So we don't need to show or assume $W \vdash \lnot \text{Thm}_U(0=1)$.

Comment: For the next part, the key point is that if $T$ is any primitive recursive theory and $\phi$ is any sentence in the language, there is a primitive recursive function that takes two inputs - a $T$-proof of $\phi$ and a $T$-proof of $\lnot \phi$ - and returns a $T$-proof of $0=1$.   The exact function depends on the formal deduction system being used, but the overall structure is to prove the tautology $\phi \to (\lnot\phi \to 0=1)$ and then use modus ponens twice.

Comment: Since $W$ extends PRA, if there is a primitive recursive procedure that takes a proof of one kind to a proof of a second kind, then the provability predicate of $W$ will be closed under that operation. For example $W \vdash [\text{Thm}_T(\phi) \land \text{Thm}_T(\psi)] \to \text{Thm}_T(\phi \land \psi)$.This is because we obtain the proof of $\phi \land \psi$ by doing a straightforward (primitive recursive) manipulation of the proofs of $\phi$ and $\psi$, which does not depend on what those proofs look like.

Comment: I think I understand. In your first comment you mean $W \vdash \text{Thm}_T(\lnot \text{Thm}_U(0=1))$ in the end instead right? As for Thm, so one could say that a primitive recursive function allows W to calculate proof-Gödelnumbers from other proof-Gödelnumbers for T without really needing to 'touch' the proofs or the provability of intermediate steps themselves.