# recursive inseparability of the two Gödelnumber-sets: theorems and 'anti-theorems' of EA

Tags: logic, recursion, proof-theory, meta-math

Here again one of my more or less basic proof-theoretic questions, working through Girards monograph from '87.

This is about exercise 1.5.10. - "recursive inseparability", on page 80.

It is this:

Let A and B be disjoint recursively enumerable subsets of $\mathbb{N}$; A and B are called $\textit{recursively inseparable}$ if and only if there is no recursive subset C of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $A \subset C, B \subset \complement{C}$.

Show that the sets $A= \{x \mid Thm_{EA}[x]\}$ and $B= \{x \mid Thm_{EA}[\langle 13, x \rangle]\}$ are recursively inseparable.

[Remark: So A is the set of the Gödelnumbers of the theorems of EA, and B is the set of the Gödelnumbers of formulae such that the negations of these formulae are theorems of EA. (13 is the Gödelnumber of the negation sign).]

So there shall be no subset C of the natural numbers such that C and its complement 'divide' A and B from each other, in the sense that the theorem-numbers are part of C and the formula-numbers, when the negated formula is a theorem, are part of C's complement.

It might have something to do with Church's theorem:
Any extension T of EA in the language of EA is either undecidable or inconsistent.
Here 'decidable' means that the set of the Gödelnumbers of the theorems of T is recursive, that is there is a recursive function that 'says yes' (say, = 0) on the theorem-numbers and 'says no' ( = 1) on any non-theorem-number.

We may assume that EA is consistent, I think, cause otherwise any formula is a theorem, and A and B are just the same, so they are not even disjoint.

I guess if there was such a C we could construct a recursive function for A, the set of theorem-numbers, contradicting Church's theorem. Because then we'd already have a recursive function 'sort of dividing' A from B, we'd only have to figure out a way in which this function can be alternated to 'deal properly' with the numbers that are not in A neither in B.

Regards and Thanks,

Ettore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already has an answer, even here on SE:
[Show that a recursively inseparable pair of recursively enumerable sets exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717815/show-that-a-recursively-inseparable-pair-of-recursively-enumerable-sets-exists/717824)

The idea lies in the diagonal lemma: The assumed separating set C can be represented by a formula $\varphi$ in EA, which in turn is connected biconditionally in EA to a formula $\tau$. This formula $\tau$ has a Gödel number. If one asks oneself where this number might lay, in C or its complement, one gets a contradition either way.

Comment: This method will work - we want to use the formula that says "I am not in $C$", I think.  There is an alternative method: if $C$ is computable, contains $A$ and is disjoint from $B$, we can use $C$ to make a computable complete theory extending $A$, which contradicts the incompleteness theorems.  Essentially, we put a formula into our complete theory if the conjunction of the formula and the formulas we have previously added is in $C$.  In particular, no formula will ever be added which is inconsistent with $A$ and the previously added formulas.

Comment: Yes I think so too..or at least a formula that is provably equivalent to that. The other way is interesting, but it surprises me that this new theory is different, it sounds as if it doesn't change because the filled in formulae were already there before, but I guess I misunderstand. By the way, I also tried to complete the proof (part (iii)) in 'ordering between theories' - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3028361/ordering-between-formal-theories-by-provability-of-consistency

Comment: The issue is that the original theory was not complete, but with the method we can make a complete extension of it. $C$ is a kind of guide that allows us to avoid ever adding an inconsistency.

Comment: I think I can see...one goes on a search for the true unprovable formulae that lay in C, beyond A so to speak, and adds them as axioms, which then are infinite many I think.

Answer (score 0):

To do the neat argument using `I am not in C' we need a bit more detail.

Suppose C a recursive set that separates the theorems and anti-theorems of our given theory, say U. (We must assume it is consistent and interprets some suitable base theory like the Tarski-Mostowski-Robinson theory R.) Then there are \Sigma^0_1-formulas S(x) and S'(x) that represent C and its complement. The problem is still that U does not need to be able verify that S' and S are disjoint. To fix that we replace S(x) by S^\ast(x) that says `there is a witness that x is in S strictly before there is a witness that x is in S' ' and we replace S'(x) by S^\dag(x) that says` there is a witness that x is in S' before or at the same time as there is a witness that x is in S'. The theory can now verify that S^\ast and S^\dag are disjoint. We apply the fixed point theorem to find \phi iff \neg, S^\ast(\phi) (confusing formulas with the numerals of their gödelnumbers).

Suppose U \vdash \phi. Then, S^\ast(\phi) is true. It follows that U \vdash S^\ast(\phi) and so U \vdash \neg \phi. A contradiction with the consistency of U. Suppose U \vdash \neg \phi. Then, S^\dag(\phi) is true and, hence, U \vdash S^\dag(phi). It follows that U \vdash \neg S^\ast(\phi). (For this step we need the pair S^\ast, S^\dag, rather than S, S'.) So, U \vdash \phi. Again this contradicts the consistency of U.

An alternative proof uses the representability of recursive functions in U. (the Kleene-style argument)

We note that Ehrenfeucht provides an example of a theory that is essentially undecidable but not recursively inseparable. So an argument using extendability to a complete theory cannot work.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).